# Plot showing information about parameters

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a list containing a function and 5 parameters (all of them can change).

```
list={x^2,0.5,0.1,5,1,1}.
```

I would like to create a plot of the function, while displaying the values of the parameters inside the plot as relevant information. The parameters should be displayed including a string about what they mean. For example I would like to see the plot and on the right side of the plot I would like to see something like: "norm = 0.5", "visibility = 0.1" and so on..
Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

list = {x^2, 0.5, 0.1, 5, 1, 1};

labels =
  {"func", "norm", "visibility", "param3", "param4", "param5"};

Row[{
  Plot[Callout[x^2, labels[[1]]], {x, 0, 1},
   ImageSize -> Medium],
  Column[StringForm["`` = ``", #[[1]], NumberForm[#[[2]], {5, 2}]] & /@
     Transpose[{Rest@labels, Rest@list}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
list= {.5,2};
Plot[a x^b, {x, 0, 1},
 PlotLabel -> 
  Column[
 {Text["norm a =" <> ToString[list[[1]]]], 
  Text["exponent b =" <> ToString[list[[2]]]]}]]
```